# lost folders after git stash -u. How to recover?

Tags: git

I had added new projects which created new folders to my .net solution folder. I had to switch so I used `git stash -u` which I thought would stash all the untracked files as well. But now when I did `git stash pop` it only brought back the changes to the files that are tracked. All the new folders and files are gone! any way to recover?

Comment: I don't think the `reflog` will be of help because I think the `pop` command updates the former to get rid of the popped commit. It's also possible the popped commit didn't apply cleanly, in which case resolving that might help your situation. If you still have your command history, you could go hunting for the popped commit hash and then run `git show <hash>^3` to show all the untracked file changes that would've been originally saved with the stashed commit. If there isn't anything, I don't think there's much else you can do.

Comment: Help other help you: include the Git version (output from `git --version`) in your question, and include the output from `git stash pop` if you still have it.